# How can I receive notifications from GCM when application is stopped

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

GCMIntentService (extends GCMBaseIntentService) doesn't receive notifications if the application is not running.

From  : http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html

Launch controls on stopped applications
Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stoppped applications. A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications.

Is there a way to get around this setting?
Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> GCMIntentService (extends GCMBaseIntentService) doesn't receive notifications if the application is not running.

Yes, it will. The rest of your question, though, has little to do with whether the application is *running*, but rather whether it has been run by the user before. What the word "stopped" means in the paragraph you quote is not "not running", but represents a state that an application is in:

- when it is first installed, before something manually invokes a component (e.g., user launches an activity)
- after the user force-stops the app, until something manually invokes a component (e.g., user launches an activity)

(and I really really wish they had come up with a more distinctive adjective than "stopped" for this...)

> Is there a way to get around this setting?

No. If the user force-stops your app, they are indicating that they do not want your app to run again, for any reason, until they manually launch it again. Your objective is to give the user no reason to force-stop your app. Note that I do mean "force-stop" (i.e., press the "Force Stop" button from Settings) -- ordinary task managers, or swiping from the Recent Tasks list in Android 4.x, does not have this effect.

Comment: By 'ordinary' task managers, do you mean task managers that don't have root access?

Comment: @Mopper: By "ordinary" task managers, I mean those that users download from the Play Store. AFAIK, root access does not change their behavior.

Comment: From what I've experienced with this, if the user swipes to remove the app from Recent Tasks, than that will also prevent the service from receiving messages.  For me only when my app is backgrounded or closed manually from the app itself will I receive GCM messages.

Comment: @Bryan: That will only be true if you are on some device where they modified the recent-tasks list behavior. For example, I just ran https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2 on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.3, successfully pushed to it, swiped it of the recent tasks lists, and successfully pushed to it again.

Comment: I probably should've noted I was using https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp to push to a mono for android device.  There is a known issue with the service, it could be that it is `monodroid`, but running on an Xperia S or Nexus 7 and removing the app from Recent Tasks prevent receiving a push notification.

Comment: @CommonsWare , can you please tell me how come twitter is doing? As there is no service running in my phone for twitter as well as it also not running in background neither in recent task list. But still i am receiving the gcm calls from twitter, but not from other apps how ?

Comment: @CommonsWare 
I killed the app. Sent some notifications. Started the app again, but those notifications were lost for ever. Is there a way to queue those or get those notifications when I starts the app again ?

Comment: @yuenshi I'm having the same issue: 1) Force Stop the app 2) Send notification A 3) App the app (the notification A is not received) 4) Send notification B (The notification B is received but not A)

Comment: @JoseF Unfortunately thats an android behavior. Since user killed the app, it meant that user don't want that app to run. If you restart the phone notifications will work. It not the app presence in background that restrict the notification but user action of removing it from background that unregister the app.

Answer (score 2):

According to Francesco Nerieri in [this android-gcm thread](https://groups.google.com/group/android-gcm/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-08/7e74aab31da818e1?rnum=11&lnk=nl&pli=1):

> So if you force stop the app, the intended behavior for ICS is for the
>   app to not receive the message.  In JB this means that GCM will also
>   unregister the app, this is an  unfortunate behavior and we are
>   working to change this (the unregister  part in JB).