# Android device not showing alert in response to remote push notification when the app is not running

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, delphi-xe8

I saw many other questions on here saying if an app is force stopped it won't receive notifications.

However, I AM NOT force stopping this app.  I am just hitting the back button.  I have also tried just hitting the home button.  In both cases no alerts.

However, if the app is running in the foreground the PushReceived event fires and the AData.Message shows the correct text.  So, it would appear that remote notifications are being sent to the device, it's just that the app is never woken up to process them.

The app is written in Delphi XE8 and I have tested this on KitKat and JellyBean, both with the same results.

I suspect the problem is in the Android Manifest file.  A copy of which is below.  Beyond this I am not sure where to go.  As I understand it when a push is received it is supposed to run a small bit of code in the Firemonkey framework that displays the push message without starting the full app.

I am using the app described in this tutorial to try to figure out why it is not working in my live app.  This used to work as I expected it to in XE7.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Remote_Notifications_%28iOS_and_Android%29

I am using the Engagement Tab on the Kinvey dashboard to send the test pushes, so I assume the server side is correct.  And as I said they are working with the app in the foreground.

Gary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.gwsystemsdns.net.pushtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">

<!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="net.gwsystemsdns.net.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="net.gwsystemsdns.net.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
<application android:persistent="False" 
    android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
    android:label="PushTest" 
    android:debuggable="True" 
    android:largeHeap="False"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">


    <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
         This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
    <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:label="PushTest"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="PushTest" />
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<category android:name="net.gwsystemsdns.net.pushtest" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

My Push Received event demonstrating the reception of foreground pushes.

```
procedure TfrmMain.PushEvents1PushReceived(Sender: TObject; const AData: TPushData);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Push Received');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Push = ' + AData.Message);
end;
```

Comment: have you read [How to handle Push notifications when the app is not running](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=106727)?

Comment: partially related (Jellybean): http://stackoverflow.com/q/11614521/80901

Comment: > have you read - Just reread it.  I concede that when the app is not running, as far as firemonkey is concerned, the Delphi Push Received even won't fire.  The problem I am having in XE8 is there is no notification at the top of the screen to tap on so even if I was interested in the startupnotification I couldn't get it.

> partially related - Interesting, but not applicable since the app is not in a stopped state.  It's only in background.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. This line was missing from the XE8 manifest template file:

```
    <%activity%>
    <service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />
    <%receivers%>
</application>
```

It goes into the AndroidManifest.template.xml file like this (immediately following the `<%receivers%>` tag:

```
    <%activity%>
    <service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService" />
    <%receivers%>
    <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
</application>
```

As per [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Multi-Device_Application_to_Receive_Push_Notifications#Android_Settings)'s docwiki.