# Syncing With Server for Missed incoming Messages from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my app i have used GCM Receiver for notification of new messages, But my question is, what if GCM does not works, or i have force quit the app, that time GCM will receive the message but will not be able to wake up my app as it was force quit. How whats app, even after i force quit the app, right after opening the app, few seconds later i received all my messages

1. How will i know if i have some missed messages, i can implement a
   manually sync, but than do i need to sync all messages and than
   compare it with my local data for any changes. Is this the efficient
   way to do it ? and how frequently should i run the periodic sync just after the user open my message fragment
2. I am just going to do downstream synching, so do i need to implement
   a syncAdapter or service is just fine

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you followed the google tutorial and builded the service to receive the callbacks, if not, please implement in that way, it is the right way. Here is the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

If you implemented in that way, do not worry, in every push Android will deliver the message for the service. If the user has force quited your app and even killed the service, android will start it again in the next push.

If the device is off when you send the message, GCM will store it for 4 weeks waiting when it can deliver the message to the device.

"How will i know if i have some missed messages"

You will never miss any message, android will try to delivery it for 4 weeks.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply, i have a working GCM and SyncAdapter too, No when you force quit the app, it won't behave the same way, I have xiomi phone MIUI 7, where i have dissable auto start, when means when i close the app, it will kill all the services, Hence the GCM receives the message, but failed to WAKE UP,

Comment: @bikash can you post the code of your SyncAdapter, the service that receives GCM messages and the part where you init the GCM with the user token?

Comment: I would suggest you to read this, if you still doubt that it will work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614521/how-can-i-receive-notifications-from-gcm-when-application-is-stopped